# Create Data Dictionary to read column from DB

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I am creating a WinForm Application that reads all the records from a certain column in a textfile. What I now need is a Data Dictionary that I can use to read records from the Database once the applications runs and prior to reading the TextFile. I need to read a specific column from the database and match it with the textfile. I am not sure how to go about creating a data dictionary. This is what I have so far.

**This is to read the textfile, which is working fine.**

```
             using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader("C:\\Test1.txt"))
            {
                string nw = file.ReadLine();
                textBox1.Text += nw + "\r\n";
                while (!file.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string text = file.ReadLine();
                    textBox1.Text += text + "\r\n";
                    string[] split_words = text.Split('|');
                    int dob = int.Parse(split_words[3]);
```

**This is what I have so far to create the Data Dictionary.**

```
  public static Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SqlDataReader`. Here is some code, you just need to modify it to suit your needs. I have added comments for you:

```
// declare the SqlDataReader, which is used in
// both the try block and the finally block
SqlDataReader rdr = null;

// Put your connection string here
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");

// create a command object. Your query will go here
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "select * from Customers", conn);

try
{
    // open the connection
    conn.Open();

    // 1. get an instance of the SqlDataReader
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        string id = (int)rdr["SomeColumn"];
        string name = (string)rdr["SomeOtherColumn"];
        dictionary.Add(id, name);
    }
}
finally
{
    // 3. close the reader
    if (rdr != null)
    {
        rdr.Close();
    }

    // close the connection
    if (conn != null)
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to make some changes and make it work. Thanks.